# Color Correction of target image based on reference color patches

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am performing a project that involves deep learning / image processing and one of the problems I'm trying to solve is to perform an image transformation based on [referencing Kodak color patches](https://www.chromaxion.com/information/kodak_color_control.html)
I've performed histogram matching and normalization but the results aren't that great with it. I'm basically looking for something like [this](https://github.com/lighttransport/colorcorrectionmatrix?tab=readme-ov-file), but the thing is this code uses a tool called Natron2, which seems to not have Python compatibility yet (since the entire project is done in Python). Moreover, the input over here asks for 24 x 3 color matrices of RGB values for reference and target images, which I'm not sure how is being attained.
Any inputs are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Have tried [histogram matching](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_histogram_matching.html) and [histogram equalization](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/02/01/opencv-histogram-equalization-and-adaptive-histogram-equalization-clahe/), but these aren't the results I'm looking for.